# Rails: A subform that when submitted updates a field in parent form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that looks like this :

```
<%= form_for :game do |game_form| %>
        <%= game_form.label :app_game_id %>
        <%= game_form.select :app_game_id, @available_app_games.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
      ....
```

Where `@available_app_games` is given from the controller, and it looks at other models different from Game.  The user is supposed to select on of those **app_games** from the drop down, but he should also be able to create a new app_game.
A form for an app_game should contain just **name** and **description**

I have two questions:

How would I create this sub form that would create a new app_game, and how would I update the:

```
<%= game_form.select :app_game_id, @available_app_games.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
```

With this new submitted **app_game** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) , may be the simplest way not to use select, but nested_form strategy.

Comment: With nested form I wouldn't accomplish this. I need a separate form.